# What the heck have I done to my Excel sheet (and how to undo it)?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a lot of Excel sheets for all sorts of things - but none has ever acted up like this one here:

[image: troubled excel sheet]

This used to be a totally normal Excel 2007 sheet which I was able to resize, maximize etc. - but not anymore. The MDI child window is fixed, both in position and size. I cannot move it around, more can I maximize it to use the full size of the screen anymore. I cannot double-click on it's title bar to maximize it either :-(

What happened? What can I do to "undo" whatever I did to it.

Any ideas? I tried to share / undo sharing, I tried to protect / unprotect the sheet - nothing seems to work...

Comment: @Chris The MDI window that contains the spreadsheet doesn't have any controls (Maximize, Minimize, etc.).

Comment: @CHris Thompson: yes, the MDI window is fixed, in position and size, and I can't seem to get it to resize or move anymore....

Comment: i think you need to remove the glass filter you have over your screen ;)

Comment: @RCIX yeah right :-)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Go to `Review > Changes > Protect Workbook`, and uncheck `Protect Structure and Windows` option. If you have set a password for it, Excel will prompt you to enter it. Otherwise, just hit enter to remove the structure and window protection.

On Excel 2011 for Mac, the process is only slighty different. On the `Review` tab, under `Protection`, click `Workbook` to remove the protection. See also the [official online help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/mac-excel-help/protect-a-workbook-HA102927961.aspx).

Comment: Thanks - I can see that that option "Protect Structure and Windows" is checked - but it's grayed out, I can't uncheck it..... any ideas??

Comment: Attempt #2 - solved it! The workbook was shared, for some weird reason. Once I've removed the sharing, I was able to uncheck that "Protect Structure and Windows" option and that solved it - thanks so much !!

Comment: This means that your workbook is protected. To remove protection, under `Review > Changes`, you should click on `Unprotect Shared Workbook` (which stands at the upper-right corner of `Changes` box). Then you can uncheck `Protect Structure and Windows` option.

Comment: While I was writing my above comment, you solved it yourself. You're welcome, and good luck with Excel ;)

Comment: thanks! the situation was such that the human factor was becoming dangerous to my computer :)

Answer (score 4):

One way that can be done is through VBA. See here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137033

And another VBA method: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=41720

See if there are any macros associated with this sheet.

It's also possible that this is due to Workbook protection: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:02brqfAzeN4J:office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052035251033.aspx+remove+maximize+minimize+spreadsheet+window+excel&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a

UPDATE: I've been able to duplicate that issue in Excel 2007, and it is a worksheet protection issue.

In Excel 2007, select the Review tab, then click the Protect Workbook button and uncheck Protect Structures and Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, that "workbook protection" link refers to Excel 2003, and in Excel 2007, there's no "Tools" / "Protection" menu :-(

Answer (score 1):

My guess is whatever is wrong the answer is in the "View" menu.

Try double clicking the title bar where it says "Einkuaf2010" to maximize it.

Comment: Tried that - no luck - nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

When changing resolution (plugging/unplugging a screen), this sometimes happens.
Save, close. Open a fresh new window. And open that file again.

Answer (score -1):

Click View tab then New Window should bring up a new window with three options.

close save and reopen.

Comment: I tried clicking on New Window on the View tab - no options were shown like "CLOSE-SAVE-REOPEN".... Are you sure about this?